# Removing <wbr> tags and grabbing the info between

Tags: python, lxml, wbr

I'm scrapping data from a webpage and have done so for a certain section that has the `<br>` tag.

```
<div class="scrollWrapper">
    <h3>Smiles</h3>
    CC=O<br>
    <button type="button" id="downloadSmiles">Download</button>
</div>
```

I solved this problem by doing the below script to output `CC=O`.

```
from lxml import html

page = requests.get('http://chem.sis.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/name/'+ substance)
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
if ("Smiles" in page.text):
        smiles = tree.xpath('normalize-space(//*[text()="Smiles"]/..//br[1]/preceding-sibling::text()[1])')
else:
        smiles = ""
```

However, as I was browsing through other pages of different chemicals I encountered some pages that had the  tag in them. I have no idea how to get rid of them while grabbing the information between them. An example is shown below with my desired output to be `c1(c2ccccc2)ccc(N)cc1`.

```
<div class="scrollWrapper">
   <h3>Smiles</h3>
   c1(c2ccccc2)<wbr>ccc(N)<wbr>cc1<br>
   <button type="button" id="downloadSmiles">Download</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to replace `<wbr>` string in the `page.text` with empty string, before you parse it into html. Since its within `<` and `>` I doubt if any of the useful info you are looking for would have it.

Example -

```
from lxml import html

page = requests.get('http://chem.sis.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/name/'+ substance)
tree = html.fromstring(page.text.replace('<wbr>',''))
if ("Smiles" in page.text):
        smiles = tree.xpath('normalize-space(//*[text()="Smiles"]/..//br[1]/preceding-sibling::text()[1])')
else:
        smiles = ""
```

Otherwise you can use @Bun's solution of using `BeautifulSoup` , or write complex xpaths.

Also, an easier xpath for your case should be -

```
'normalize-space(//*[text()="Smiles"]/following-sibling::text()[1])'
```

Rather than finding out the Smiles, element and then taking its parent then find out the first  `br` element that is its descendent then taking its preceding sibling and then its text.

You should directly take the following sibling for the `Smiles` element and then its text.

Comment: Interesting, but way too complex.

Comment: Sorry how is it complex? He already has the xpath and working code for reading the text before the `<br>` tag, he just needs to add the code to replace `<wbr>` with empty string and the second type of html pages should give him the result he wants right?

Comment: I mean, not the procedure itself, but just to be clear, @Bun's answer is easier than using this: `'normalize-space(//*[text()="Smiles"]/following-sibling::text()[1])'`

Comment: Yes, true, That was just a suggestion, the actual answer was the replacement part (a suggestion over his OP's own xpath , incase he does not want to go BeautifulSoup route).

Comment: Thanks! I followed your suggestion and did it in a kind of weird way, but it works.     
if ("Smiles" in page.text):
        if ('<wbr>' in page.text): 
            tree = html.fromstring(page.text.replace('<wbr>',''))
            smiles = tree.xpath('normalize-space(//*[text()="Smiles"]/following-sibling::text()[1])')
        else: 
            smiles = tree.xpath('normalize-space(//*[text()="Smiles"]/following-sibling::text()[1])')
    else:
        smiles = ""

Answer (score 1):

`<wbr>`

> The  (Word Break Opportunity) tag specifies where in a text it would be ok to add a line-break. Tip: When a word is too long, or you are afraid that the browser will break your lines at the wrong place, you can use the  element to add word break opportunities.

I use `BeautifulSoup` to parse this data.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = """
<div class="scrollWrapper">
   <h3>Smiles</h3>
   c1(c2ccccc2)<wbr>ccc(N)<wbr>cc1<br>
   <button type="button" id="downloadSmiles">Download</button>
</div>
"""

soup = bs(html, "html.parser")
rows = soup.get_text().split()
print(rows[1])
```

Output:

```
   c1(c2ccccc2)ccc(N)cc1
```

Comment: Good point and answer, but note that his desired output would be `c1(c2ccccc2)ccc(N)cc1`, and not the other two words.

Comment: I'm trying to not use BeautifulSoup as I would just like to stick to lxml for now, but if I can't get around it I'll give soup a shot.

Comment: Fixed. Please take a look. @J.C.Rocamonde

Comment: Not being bias, BeautifulSoup is much simpler. :) @TimTom

Comment: Yeah, now much better. I didn't know about BeautifulSoup. Seems to be promising, I think I'll give it a shot, as @TimTom said.

Answer (score 0):

Just to point out: you can get rid of a specific string by doing:

```
str.replace(old, "")
```

So for instance:

```
"c1(c2ccccc2)<wbr>ccc(N)<wbr>cc1<br>".replace("<wbr>", "").replace("<br>", "")
```

However, the other answers get closer to the desired result.

Comment: Could I do a logic statement like 
`if("<wbr>" in page.text)
     smiles = tree.xpath('normalize-space(//*[text()="Smiles"]/..//wbr[1]/preceding-sibling::text()[1])').replace("wbr>", "").replace("<br>", "")`?

Comment: Yes, but the replace method does not fail if no text matching the criteria is encountered, it just simply returns the same string. However, this is just a simple suggestion. Better take a look at the other answers.